# Why I cannot apply constraints to the photo in the UITableView header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

In my storyboard I have a `UITableView` and above the dynamic cells I added a `UIView` to keep there a photo and some labels.

Currently, I want to apply constraints to the photo so that it reaches the top, left and right side of the screen and keeps the aspect ratio. However, the storyboard looks like this:

[image]

The constraints for photo are:

[image]

[image]

However, as you see, the constraints are marked in red and when I run the app the photo is not stretched properly.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: A few things: Are you using the ratio to keep the imageView at a certain aspect ratio, or are you doing it because you hope the actual image to be at the correct aspect ratio?  They are totally different things.  Also, if you're trying to set your imageView to have a 240:300 (4:5) ratio I assume you don't want that to be a 4:5 ratio to the superview - you want it to be in relation to itself.  That is the reason your have red constraints.  Delete that constraint and set the ratio relative to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this programmatically. It is pretty simple to create a custom view and set it as your header view. You can either create a UIView with a UIImageView inside of `viewForHeader` or by assigning it to the entire table with `tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView`.